# Yet another net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING in chrome

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome

I'm facing the error "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" on a specific page only with chrome after I reload it.

When I restart apache it fixes the issue for the first load, if I hit refresh I face the same error again.

Can you help me diagnose this kind of chrome trolling? I tried to remove everything in my .htaccess but I faced the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded php and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i also face this same problem,when i use chrome to run my web. 
before the problem is fixed:
1、use $.getJSON('url***',params,callback_function);
and then run my web,the "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" is showed.

after a long time trying,when i put one '/' to url,the "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" idoesn't show .the problem seems liked be fixed.which is more amazing is that the number the '/' doesn't face the result.the problem is decided by whether '/' exsits in url.